# Insert markup without loss of jQuery Mobile styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Hi I'm trying to make a collapsable list with dynamic data. I'm having a problem when I'm trying to insert some markup inside a div. More specifically all the html doesn't get styled by jQuery Mobile.

Here is a simplified version of how I'm trying to do it:

**THE HTML**

```
<div id="testdiv">
</div>
```

**THE JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    append();
});

function append() {
    var str =   '' +
                '<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="d">' +
                    '<div data-role="collapsible" id="monday">' +
                        '<h2>Måndag</h2>' +
                        '<form>' +
                            '<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">' +
                                '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-monday-Coachtid" id="checkbox-monday-Coachtid">' +
                                '<label for="checkbox-monday-Coachtid">Coachtid</label>' +
                                '<button data-theme="b">Spara</button>' +
                            '</fieldset>' +
                        '</form>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '';
    $("#testdiv").html(str).testdiv;
}
```

When I try to put ***str*** in like this with Javascript I end up with something like this:
[image]

But when just paste ***str*** as if it were written as is in the html file it looks like this:
[image]

***My Question, is there any way to insert html inside a div and make it get rendered by jQuery Mobile and get that styling?***

Thanks

Comment: try $('#testdiv').trigger('create') after you add items. The whole div will be rendered again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#testdiv').trigger('create')
```